# Changing masking colour around waveform on custom Soundcloud player

Tags: api, soundcloud

before I start I'm not a developer, so apologies in advance for any potentially daft questions. Our developer has just integrated a custom soundcloud player for our website http://www.samplephonics.com/ (see when you hover over the top 8 or recent sample packs) but I want to change the light grey background colour around the waveform to white.

As far as I am aware it's configured so that the light grey mask displays the shape of the waveform as a hole, which then has solid light grey, grey and dark grey images behind to show the apparent colour of the waveform in idle, loading and playing states..

Does anyone know how we can change this mask to white, or have any ideas I can send his way? He used this example as a starting point for creating the player: http://static.soundcloud.com/demos/soundcloud-custom-player/examples/sc-player-minimal.html

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Soundcloud custom widget : change container background color w/o waveform.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720881/soundcloud-custom-widget-change-container-background-color-w-o-waveform-js)

Answer (score 1):

I've previously answered this here – https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731623/236135

> unless the library you want to use for waveform customisation is using HTML5 canvas, you won't be able to use change the color of that chrome (so no, not possible with either HTML5 Widget API or Custom Player API)

In short, you'd have to use canvas or manipulate the images on the server and retrieve them from server.